# Erro ao fazer If Else Condition Inline no angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, if, else

Estou tentanto fazer uma renderização condicional de imagens, porém o que está sendo mostrado na tela é o código em si e não o resultado do if else condition.

**Segue o código:**

```html
<td>
                  {{
                    Time.ultimos_jogos[0] === "v" ? <img src="../img/vitoria.svg" alt="vitoria"> : "" ||
                    Time.ultimos_jogos[0] === "e" ? <img src="../img/empate.svg" alt="empate"> : "" ||
                    Time.ultimos_jogos[0] === "d" ? <img src="../img/derrota.svg" alt="derrota"> : "" 
                  }}
              </td>
```

**Resultado na tela:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já utilizei um código semelhante a esse com React e funcionou, o que muda é somente as chaves, que no React são simples({}) e no angular são duplas({{}}).

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Os dados recebidos em Time.ultimos_jogos[0] são "v", "e" ou "d". dependendo do tipo de resultado quero renderizar um tipo de imagem. Se for "v" por exemplo aparece a imagem de vitória, "e" aparece imagem de empate e "d" imagem de derrota. Ficou um pouco mais claro?

Comment: Veja, isso funciona: {{
                    Time.ultimos_jogos[0] === "v" ? "vitoria" : "" ||
                    Time.ultimos_jogos[0] === "e" ? "empate" : "" ||
                    Time.ultimos_jogos[0] === "d" ? "derrota" :  ""
                  }}
Mas quando se trata de imagens no lugar da string não funciona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provavelmente deva estar aprendendo **Angular**, mas, nada que uma busca rápida na web, principalmente na [documentação](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) não resolveria. A sintaxe para condicionais em template não é essa. A condição vai dentro da `tag` Html e não dentro das chaves:

> Exemplo da própria documentação

```
<div *ngIf="condition">Content to render when condition is true.</div>
```

Isso é o básico, agora para o seu exemplo vc tem maneiras de fazer o que deseja, que é mostrar determinada imagem conforme uma determinada condição.

##### 1° maneira - ter cada div com a sua condição:

```
<td *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[0] === 'v' ">
  <img src="../img/vitoria.svg" alt="vitoria">
</td>

<td *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[0] === 'e' ">
  <img src="../img/empate.svg" alt="empate">
</td>

<td *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[0] === 'd' ">
  <img src="../img/derrota.svg" alt="derrota">
</td>
```

##### 2° maneira - fazer as condições no componente e trabalhar o atributo `src` e `alt` da imagem com [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding):

```
public img: string;
public alt: string;

ngOnInit() {
   ... Times ...
   
   if(Time.ultimos_jogos[0] === 'v') {
     this.img = '../img/vitoria.svg';
     this.alt = 'vitoria';
   }
   else if(Time.ultimos_jogos[0] === 'e') {
     this.img = '../img/empate.svg';
     this.alt = 'empate';
   }
   else {
     this.img = '../img/derrota.svg';
     this.alt = 'derrota';
   }
}
```

---

```
<td>
  <img [src]="img" [alt]="alt">
</td>
```

**OBS: No seu comentário disse que fez com string e funcionou, realmente funciona, pq qualquer expressão JavaScript válida dentro de uma interpolação moustache `{{ }}` funciona, agora inserir tags html dentro delas não!**

Comment: Quem sinalizou essa resposta como sendo de baixa qualidade poderia por favor informar qual o motivo, pois não vi nada de errado com a publicação.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Cara. Mas tem alguma forma de eu fazer tudo isso dentro de apenas um <td></td>?

Comment: Tem ué, a segunda maneira do exemplo que dei. Vc só renderiza uma `td` na tela, a td com a imagem que corresponder a condição. Eu já até imagino o próximo passo que vc precise dar aí, é aprender a utilizar **ngFor**, pra não ter que ficar fazendo isso `Time.ultimos_jogos[0]`, `Time.ultimos_jogos[1]`, etc... E sim pegar esses valores dinamicamente.

Comment: Eu fiz de outro jeito que atendeu meu objetivo seguindo o que você falou de NgIf, dá uma olhada na outra resposta que adicionei aqui. Realmente preciso aprender outras práticas pra simplificar o código, vlw.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui antigir o objetivo que esperava fazendo algumas modificações no código e seguindo as orientações de NgIf passadas pelo colega LeAndrade aqui na questão. A diferença é que o código está com NgIf e tudo sendo sendo feito dentro de apenas um td.

O Código que resolveu meu problema ficou assim:

```html
<td>
                  <!-- Primeiro Indice do Array -->
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[0] === 'v' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/vitoria.svg" alt="vitoria">
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[0] === 'e' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/empate.svg" alt="empate">
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[0] === 'd' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/derrota.svg" alt="derrota">
                  </ng-container>
                  <!-- Segundo Indice do Array -->
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[1] === 'v'">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/vitoria.svg" alt="vitoria">
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[1] === 'e' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/empate.svg" alt="empate">
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[1] === 'd' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/derrota.svg" alt="derrota">
                  </ng-container>
                  <!-- Terceiro Indice do Array -->
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[2] === 'v' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/vitoria.svg" alt="vitoria">
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[2] === 'e' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/empate.svg" alt="empate">
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[2] === 'd' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/derrota.svg" alt="derrota">
                  </ng-container>
                  <!-- Quarto Indice do Array -->
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[3] === 'v' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/vitoria.svg" alt="vitoria">
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[3] === 'e' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/empate.svg" alt="empate">
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[3] === 'd' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/derrota.svg" alt="derrota">
                  </ng-container>
                  <!-- Quinto Indice do Array -->
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[4] === 'v' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/vitoria.svg" alt="vitoria">
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[4] === 'e' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/empate.svg" alt="empate">
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[4] === 'd' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/derrota.svg" alt="derrota">
                  </ng-container>
                  <!-- Sexto Indice do Array -->
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[5] === 'v' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/vitoria.svg" alt="vitoria">
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[5] === 'e' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/empate.svg" alt="empate">
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="Time.ultimos_jogos[5] === 'd' ">
                    <img src="https://tabela-campeonato-brasileiro.vercel.app/img/derrota.svg" alt="derrota">
                  </ng-container>
</td>
```

O resultado foi esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se essa é a melhor forma de fazer isso, achei que o código ficou um pouco denso, mas foi a forma que encontrei. Se alguém souber de um jeito melhor e puder ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Isso aí, ta no caminho. Como disse antes o próximo passo seu deveria ser aprender a trabalhar com instrução de *loop*, como `(for, forEach, map, filter, etc...)` para eliminar ter que fazer tudo na mão e deixar o código fazer isso por vc. Dá uma olhada neste link que é o que precisa agora: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf